# How to to get document data from a firebase collection?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Hello working on a real time chat app in react, that uses firebase as a backend. I'm trying to create a way for a user to switch between chat rooms they've previously visited, without having to go back to the home screen and reenter the same chat room name again to enter it. as shown in the picture below.

[image]

so far I'm able to get a specific document, and console.log its data, but I'm completely lost on how to get the latest document added to my "messages" collection, and separate them based on which "room" they're in, so the user could choose between them.

[image]

here is the code I have so far.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import {doc, getDoc} from 'firebase/firestore';
import {auth, dataBase} from '../firebase-config.js';
import '../styles/chats.css'

function Chats() {
  const [firebaseDoc, setFirebaseDoc] = useState();

  const getDocument = async () => {
  const docRef = doc(dataBase, "messages", "k21jzBORYMzD6YcTUG6c");
  const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
  setFirebaseDoc(docSnap.data())

  console.log(docSnap.data());
}

  return (
    <>
        <div className="chats-container">
            <button onClick={getDocument}>get firebase collection documents</button>
            <div>
              
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Chats;
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things to consider:

1. Firestore is great for storing "business objects" such as "Chat Rooms", "User Profiles", "Sales Orders", "Product Descriptions" and "Game Summaries".  Each Document is a "data map" -- a nested set of key-value pairs.  Each document can hold up to 1MB of data, which is approximately the size of all the text in the three Lord Of The Rings books combined.
2. Firestore is not great for small and/or rapidly changing data.  I consider using Realtime Database for uses such as "chat messages", "likes", "ratings", "game moves", etc.

Many apps use both Firestore (business objects) and RTDB (small, rapidly changing data).

The way you have modeled your documents in the screenshot above, you will need to read ALL of the messages to figure out which "channels" exist.  At the very least, you want to keep a list of existing chat rooms separate from your Messages -- each chat room could be its own document in a "Rooms" collection or you could simply keep a single document (set its ID to "Rooms" or something like that) which contains an array of all of the rooms.  That way you can get the list of rooms without having to read every single Message.